# (Morse) non-degenerate iff transverse to the zero section

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

So Morse $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ has nondegenerate critical point p iff $df|_{p}\pitchfork 0$-section.

Attempt

nondegenarate p iff Hessian has full rank at p  iff

$Im(D|_{p}df)=T_{df(p)}^{*}M\Leftrightarrow Im(D|_{p}df)+T_{df(p)}$

$(0_{section})=T_{df(p)}^{*}M+T_{df(p)}M=T_{df(p)}(T^{*}M) \Leftrightarrow  df \pitchfork 0_{section}$.

is this correct?

Is the tangent space at the 0-section zero dimensional since it is the constant map?

Comment: do you need any more information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things aren't quite right here, TKM. First, the Hessian $d^2f(p)$ is a symmetric bilinear map $T_pM\times T_pM\to\Bbb R$, so your image statement is not right. Second, you're talking about $df$ as a section of $T^*M$ and you want it to be transverse to the zero section of that bundle. Here's how you should approach it: Work in local coordinates, so assume $M=\Bbb R^n$ and $p=0$. Then the section corresponds to the function $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ given by $\Phi(x)=(x,df(x))$, i.e., $\Phi(x)=\big(x,(\partial f/\partial x_1,\dots,\partial f/\partial x_n)\big)$. To say $\Phi$ is transverse to $\Bbb R^n\times \{0\}$ at $0$ is to say $\text{im}(d\Phi_0) \oplus \Bbb R^n\times\{0\} = \Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$, which is to say that the linear map associated to the bilinear form $d^2f(p)$ is surjective, which is precisely the definition of nondegeneracy.

Comment: The Hessian matrix at p is this linear map.

Comment: can you write it also in terms of tangent spaces (like $T_{p}T^{*}M$)?

Comment: Yes, but the Hessian is usually considered as a symmetric bilinear form, not as a linear map. Talking about this without local coordinates requires you to know how to differentiate sections of a vector bundle. In general, this necessitates a *connection* on the vector bundle, but at a *zero* of a section $s$, one can check that the derivative $Ds$ is well-defined as a map $T_pM\to T_pM$ (or $E_p$ for the general vector bundle). This is called the *intrinsic derivative*.

Comment: Is the tangent space at the 0-section zero dimensional since it is the constant map?

Comment: $T_{(p,df(p))}(T^{*}M))= Im(H_{p}(f))+ ?$

Comment: No, the tangent space of the zero section at $(p,0)$ is a copy of $T^*_pM$. The tangent space at any other point is, of course, isomorphic to $T_pM \times T^*_pM$, but there's no natural way to pick out the $T_pM$ subspace. That's where connections come in. You really can work with the Hessian in an intrinsic way *only* at the critical points of $f$.